# translate3d working properly in chrome but not in other browsers

Tags: animation, css, 3d

**Here is my demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Gf9Bn/5/

From my demo, it's working fine in chrome, but in firefox and other browsers its showing like a normal view. Guys if you know the spot, please shoot it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the perspective value wrong in Firefox:
perspective(200) should be perspective(200px).

Even if W3C CSS 3D Transforms Module Level 3 specify none |  as values, px is required in Firefox but is calculated as number.

Check this version:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gf9Bn/20/

Answer (score 0):

Read the compatibility tables for support of CSS3.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d